# Beamer: Exclude TOC from increasing pagecounter

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I would like to exlude the TOC slide which appear when ever a new 'section' starts to increase the pagecounter, automatically. Furthermore, it would be nice to hide the pagenumber of these TOC slides.

An example:

Currently its like this:
Titlepage ( in the right bottom corner: 1 / 34)
new section / TOC (2/34)
Content 1 (3/34)
new section / TOC (4/34)
...

Desired:
Titlepage ( in the right bottom corner: 1 / 34)
new section / TOC  (no pagenumber )
Content 1 (2/34)
new section / TOC (no pagenumber )
...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do not want to count the TOC slides in your pagecounter, you can reset the pagecounter after these slides with `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`. However this also affects the total number of frames, so it would for example be

> 1/32, none, 2/32, none ...

instead of your proposed

> 1/34, none, 2/34, none ...

To hide the page number on the TOC slides, you can try the option `\begin{frame}[plain]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{picture}(54,12.5)(0,0)
        \put(0.9,0.52){%
            \begin{minipage}[b][12.5mm][c]{112.5mm}
                \raggedleft
                \insertpagenumber/\insertpresentationendpage
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}

    \frame{
        \titlepage
    }

    \AtBeginSection[]{
        \begin{frame}[plain]
            \frametitle{Overview}
            \tableofcontents[currentsection]
            \addtocounter{page}{-1}
        \end{frame}
    }

\section{test1}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

\section{test2}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

### Edit:

Based on @Tom's comment, here a more elegant solution

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
        \frametitle{Overview}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

    \frame{
        \titlepage
    }

    \section{test1}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \section{test2}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The `noframenumbering` option for a frame prevents the frame number from being incremented.

Comment: @Tom: This is true, but it does not prevent the footline to be shown, so it would have to be used in combination with the `plain` option.

Comment: That's true. I meant that the option could be used instead of `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`.

Comment: @Tom: thanks for clarification, added this option to my answer

Comment: Not sure why, but I had to use `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` instead of `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`

Comment: @mxmlnkn Well, this depends if you show the frame or the page number at the bottom of the slide. The first example in this answer shows page numbers, the second one uses frame numbers.